# Как вернуть из функции список? (Ошибка склеивания списков)

Tags: python, return

```
import random
def hoare_sorting(s):
    if len(s) > 1:
        rand_number = random.choice(s)
        less = [elem for elem in s if elem < rand_number]
        equal = [elem for elem in s if elem == rand_number]
        greather = [elem for elem in s if elem > rand_number]
        return hoare_sorting(less) + equal + hoare_sorting(greather)
s = [1, 2, 1, 7, 3, 2]   
new_list = hoare_sorting(s)
```

Ошибка: Возникло исключение: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Comment: у вас же проблема не в возврате списка, а в том, что какой-то из элементов возвращает None. Сделайте вывод на печать перед return  каждого элемента, который вы возвращаете, наверняка найдете ошибку

Comment: Да, с вами согласен hoare_sorting(less) и hoare_sorting(greather) имеют тип None. Как мне исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если длина списка 0 или 1 то условие в `if` не сработает поэтому надо добавить `else` где мы будем возвращать список без изменений

```
import random
def hoare_sorting(s):
    if len(s) > 1:
        rand_number = random.choice(s)
        less = [elem for elem in s if elem < rand_number]
        equal = [elem for elem in s if elem == rand_number]
        greather = [elem for elem in s if elem > rand_number]
    
        return hoare_sorting(less) + equal + hoare_sorting(greather)
    else:
        return s
```

Comment: Действительно, огромное спасибо